# How to unit test in pytest a method changing class attributes?

Tags: python, pytest

I am using a class attribute in a way that mimics the singleton pattern - it is a pandas dataframe which is manipulated by a lot of methods and which should exist as a single instance. In a way it stands for a table in a relational database.

How to unit test a method which manipulates this class attribute?

In the code snippet below this is the `add_product` method.

```
@dataclass
class Item():
    
    id: int 
        
@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Appliance (Item):     
    
    model: str
   
class Inventory:
    appliances = pd.DataFrame()
    
    @classmethod
    def add_product(cls, prod):
     ##add a new row
```

Comment: Why don't you modify the class variable by calling the method and then check if it has the expected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only goal is to test the effects on the single global value, and you can't change the implementation, then you test it like you'd test any other global. You check the value of the global after running the changes.

```
def my_test():
    # Pseudocode, obviously, just to get the point across
    sample_product = Product()
    Inventory.add_product(sample_product)
    assert Inventory.devices[-1].name == sample_product
```

However, it sounds to me like there's nothing *inherently* singleton-like about your `Inventory`. Sure, your application might just need one of them, but the core functionality of the class could be an instance, not a global. Consider separating the convenient "global-ness" you need for your application from the actual functionality, which still only depends on a single Pandas dataframe.

```
class Inventory:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def add_product(self, product):
        ...
```

Then you can still have a global "default" version of it.

```
class DefaultInventory:
    implementation = Inventory(read_df_for_my_app())

    # Delegators, if you want the convenient syntax
    @classmethod
    def add_product(cls, product):
        cls.implementation.add_product(product)
```

Now, even though your main application still uses `DefaultInventory.add_product` everywhere, all of your *code* which implements this is in a nice, modular `Inventory` class. Your tests can make an `Inventory` with whatever dataframes you want to mock up, and it'll have no effect on the other tests.

Additionally, if you're really thinking of this as a stand-in for a relational database, you should look into ORMs and specifically the [active record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). That is, you can have an *active record class* which is tied to a particular row of the database (or Pandas dataframe, in your case). Changes to instances of that class affect the database live. Then `Inventory` simply provides instances of this live access class.

```
class ProductRecord:

    def __init__(self, df_row):
        self.df_row = df_row

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.df_row['id']

    @id.setter
    def id(self, value):
        self.df_row['id'] = value

class Inventory:

    # ... Initializer ...

    def add_product(self, prod):
        new_row = self.df.append(build_row(prod))
        return ProductRecord(new_row)
```

Now, rather than expecting your users to interface with Pandas directly, they talk to an ordinary Python class `ProductRecord` that *happens* to represent a row of a Pandas dataframe. Changes to the class variables will, by virtue of the `@property` decorator, translate to live changes in the dataframe.

The bottom line here is: When a piece of code is hard to test, it's probably too tightly coupled. Breaking it apart will make it easier to test and will, as a convenient side effect, make your code easier to reason about too.

Comment: Thanks, your post really helped me reason about the architecture. One question - is the `DefaultInventory` class really necessary? It is, more or less, just an instantiation of `Inventory`. To me it looks like it can be replaced with a global/module variable e.g. `defaultInventory = Inventory()`.

Comment: It certainly could. I was just trying to stay as close to your current architecture as possible in that example, but you're quite right that it's just a module-level variable. The one benefit of putting it in a class is that it could later be turned into a computed value or something else without it being a breaking change, so if you make it module-level I'd recommend having an accessor in the same module (`def get_default_inventory()`), so you still have that option in the future.